# send an ajax request phonegap

Tags: android, ajax, cordova

I d' like to send an ajax request on a website but I have a strange result:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://mydomain.com/test.json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        alert('Ok');
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(data.responseText);
        alert('FAIL !!!');
    }
});
```

test.json is

```
{
    ttt: 1,
    ttt: 3,
    test:{
        aa: 1,
        bb: 2
    }
}
```

So I have the alert fail but im my console.log I have the content of my json file

Why the error return a result ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sample:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://mydomain.com/test.json'}),
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        alert('Ok');
    }),
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(textStatus);
        alert('FAIL !!!');
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, thanks to you I saw that my json was bad formated.

Comment: I'm glad to have helped you!